# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.8): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. Error react-native AVD

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've been getting this error working on react-native. Firebase connects normally, with auth(), but I can't seem to get it working for firestore. The problem only occurred on Android Emulator, the iOS one is working fine.
[error only occurred on Android Virtual Device, the iOS one work perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIJ8R.jpg)

Here is Firebase file (removed some information about the app)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: '',
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db };
```

Here is where I used Firestore function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn/dist';
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import { doc, serverTimestamp, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../Firebase';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const ModalScreen = () => {
  const tw = useTailwind();
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [job, setJob] = useState('');
  const [age, setAge] = useState('');

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const inCompleteForm = !image || !job || !age;

  const updateUserProfile = () => {
    setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
      id: user.uid,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: image,
      job,
      age,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
    })
      .then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('Home');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  };
```

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind-rn/dist';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper';
import { doc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../Firebase';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const tw = useTailwind();
  const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);
  const { user, logOut } = useAuth();
  const swipeRef = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), snapshot => {
      if (!snapshot.exists) navigation.navigate('Modal');
    });
  }, []);
```

Error

```
[2022-03-15T06:49:42.961Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.8): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
 WARN  [2022-03-15T06:53:06.868Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.8): Connection WebChannel transport errored: {"defaultPrevented": false,
```

Comment: Check if emulator has internet connection

Comment: I can access something like youtube, facebook, google on the emulator normally

Answer (score 2):

i got the same problem, try to see [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6036#issuecomment-1072237987) or the code i will give bellow if it can solve the problem :)

```js
import { initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const database = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true
})
```

const "database" in my example is not the same as "db" in your code, keep the both